# Stata finds the wrong Python environment

Tags: python, stata, environment

I don't really understand about Python environments and would appreciate some help.

Trying to run Python in Stata and Stata does not find the library I want to import (requests). I have confirmed it is installed in Terminal (pip install requests). I can import it just fine in Jupyter Notebook (this is where I normally use Python).

When I type

```
import sys print(sys.executable)
```

In Jupyter, I get:

```
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

In Stata, I get:

```
/usr/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

What do I need to change? I think the Anaconda one is the one I want to use everywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by using

```
python set exec /opt/anaconda3/bin/python, permanently
```

Permanently option was required to prevent it from reverting when Stata was restarted.

I would still like to understand better what the other python3 environment is/how it got there!